# VBA FormulaArray range class error when the Characters are less than 255

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, formula

The VBA .FormulaArray seems to have a problem with my range. I've read that it can't handle over 255 characters, but mine is only about 108, but I could be understanding it wrong.

It gives an

> Error 1004:
>   Unable to set FormulaArray property of the Range class.

I've tried leaving the formula in the table column and let it automatically populate when the table is filled with the Macro, but the problem is that the Index array table doesn't exist yet before the Macro starts running.

Also tried leaving it as text and then changing the column to "general" but it doesn't work. And I know it will create a problem changing it to an array formula this way as well.

This is the code I'm using:

```
With wsOutdated.ListObjects("Table_Outdated_Stock_Counts")
        .ListColumns("Ranging").DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = "General"
        .ListColumns("Ranging").DataBodyRange.FormulaArray = "=INDEX(Table_DispoData[[Class]],MATCH([@Article]&[@Site],Table_DispoData[Article]&Table_DispoData[Site],0),1)"
    End With
```

I need the table column to populate automatically with the array formula.
It works for other columns(they are not array formulas though and only need to match a single value).

Comment: Does the formula work if you add it manually to that range (as array formula)? Is it actually an array formula or is it a normal formula? Then use `.Formula` instead.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, if the macro finished running and the table has data in, the formula works if I add it in manually(it is an array formula) because I have more than 1 criteria to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could try:

```
.ListColumns("Ranging").DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).FormulaArray = "=INDEX(Table_DispoData[[Class]],MATCH([@Article]&[@Site],Table_DispoData[Article]&Table_DispoData[Site],0),1)"
```

Instead of :

```
.ListColumns("Ranging").DataBodyRange.FormulaArray = "=INDEX(Table_DispoData[[Class]],MATCH([@Article]&[@Site],Table_DispoData[Article]&Table_DispoData[Site],0),1)"
```

and see if it works for you!

**Explanation:**

> Your code is trying to write Array formula to multiple cells simultaneously which is not allowed. 
>   If you try to do this in Excel then it will return an error "Multi-cell array formulas aren't allowed in tables".

Comment: Thanks this worked! First it only filled the first cell because the formula was added after the table was filled, so I just moved it higher up in the code to before the table is filled, that way it populated the column at the same time when data was filled in. Thanks!